# How can i remove all of my existing html code below my javascript using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find a simple code i can use in my javascript to remove all of the existing html below my javascript. I want it to look just plain below my javascript(i already have something to remove the stuff above).

Comment: give it a `class`, `id`, or a `name` to the section below your javascript and this will be easy.

Comment: You're emptying the contents of a web-page but retaining the JavaScript? What does your HTML look like? Because you seem to be making this far more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for remove all of the existing html this:

```
 document.body.innerHTML="";
```

Or in the specific div using

```
document.getElementById("divs").innerHTML=""
```

Using `Jquery` you can use :

1. The jQuery [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method is similar to calling `innerText`/`textContent` on a HTML Element.
2. The jQuery [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method is similar to calling `innerHTML` on a HTML Element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to remove some section from your code.

As example :

`$( "button" ).click(function() {  $( ".currentdiv" ).empty();});`

As button u can choice anything that u will activate to remove code, and then choice what `div` or any tag components you want to remove.

Enjoy.